# Block comment syntax colouring being lost while moving, but redraw will fix

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim9

I frequently use block comments to disable sections of terraform code using `/*` to start disabling and `*/` to complete. As expected, the code will turn "grey" and lose syntax highlights.

However, when I move the cursor so that the opening `/*`  scrolls off the top of the screen, the previously "grey" code suddenly starts highlighting again.  If I stop moving and CTRL-L to redraw the problem goes away and the code goes "grey" again - although in some unidentified cases redraw never fixes this - it's a little frustrating as I never am sure what code is live or not.

I'm on Windows, using VIM 9.0, the [vim-terraform](https://github.com/hashivim/vim-terraform) pack, gruvbox colorscheme

I believe I did not have this issue to such a great extent with Vim 8.0.  I recall attempting Vim 8.2 and reverting to 8.0 after a few days and I'm only seeing this issue again since updating to 9.0 and it's pretty annoying.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with syntax file, colorscheme file or gvim itself - so any pointers on how to narrow it down?

Cheers
Pete

Comment: What "vim-terraform pack"? If it provides a syntax script then you should use their issue tracker.

Comment: Sounds like a syntax sync issue; there are some things you can do to increase the sync range, but it might be a symptom of how the syntax file is constructed.

Comment: I've added a link to the terraform plugin I'm using.  I have logged a ticket there - but I wasnot sure if the issue was syntax or colouring or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the thread for [this issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2790) led me to add the following to my vimrc:

```
  "To keep syntax active?
  "https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2790
  set redrawtime=10000 
  set regexpengine=1 "old engine explicitly
```

I had `redrawtime` only and that appeared to fix the issue, but it did not seem to be reliable..

EDIT:
I've set this in my `_vimrc` and for now seems to be working..

```
syntax sync fromstart
```

Comment: I take it back - this solution eventually became unreliable too.  I'm not sure why it works sometimes and not others